# What does cut and paste from browser to plain text do to XML

Tags: xml

I have an XML file I downloaded.  I opened it with Firefox and, not surprisingly, it's just a long string of unformatted text.  I was planning to do some work with the plain text so I hit select all, then copy/pasted it into a text editor (gedit in Linux Mint).  To my great pleasure, the result was nicely formated with all the line breaks and blank lines that I saw when viewing the file on the web, before downloading it (no tabs or other formatting, just the line breaks).

Could someone explain why this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 explanations:

1. XML file was formatted and all the whitechars (spaces, tabulators etc) has been copied to the clipboard, but firefox ommited them.
2. XML was NOT formatted, and firefox did it for you.

What is formatting of XML (in this case)? Adding whitechars to create chierarchial stucture. So to allow you to "export" the data in formatted form, firefox copies the content with whitechars to the clipboard. That is why you are are getting formatted XML in the editor.

The last 3rd option is, that firefox did nothing more then copy text only, but your text editor did the magic - detect that pasted content is an XML and formatted it four you.

All depends how did you copy your XML. Was it from the source view of the XML? You would see already formatted structure or maybe the "web view" where XML tags are threated like HTML and simply ommited from the output (cus you dont see HTML tags on the web pages, only content right ?? ;))
.